# Can I poll WIndows for HID Input?

Tags: windows, input, usb, hid

HID USB information and examples are fairly spotty.  So far the only example I have found for getting input requires response to a Windows message that input is available.  Is this the only way to get the current state of Buttons and Values in Windows or is there a polled approach?  Could you point me at a  good example (C# woudl be awesome but I can convert C code.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should check out:

[HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) is a cross-platform library for accessing HIDs, and it might do what you want.

Microsoft provides a [Sample HID client app (hclient)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/hclient) which might do what you want.  I have not looked into the details of how it works, but it is open source and there is even a package for it in [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) if you just want to try it out quickly without compiling anything.